# How to remove "x" mark from staticmap images made by Mapbox's Static Tile API

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio, mapbox-api-staticimages

I'm now trying Mapbox's Static Tiles API.
I customed my own style with Mapbox Studio and succeeded in generating image from Mapbox's Static Tiles API with this my own style, but there're many "x" marks near every edge of road-path in this map image.

"x" mark from StaticMap images:

[image: "x" mark from StaticMap images]

What are those "x" marks and How can I retrieve them?

I'm glad at any suggestion. Thank you for advance.

I can see these "x" marks in Mapbox Studio when turning on the "Static tiles" option in debug setting, but can't handle hiding theme.

[image: Mapbox Studio]

Comment: Does the marks disapear at a certain zoom level?